# Scala - how to change compiler behavior (automatic conversion to floating point types)?

Tags: scala, floating-point, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

For example, this code compiles and outputs `false`, because Scala compiler implicitly converts `Int`s to `Double`s instead of creating `List[AnyVal]`, and this looks strange to me, because this can lead to data loss (floating-point types are not precise, for example; and it can do similar thing with other types that may have dangerous implicit conversions). Why designers of Scala have chosen to do it this way? (I'm using version 2.9)

```
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val x = List(3, 2)
        val y = List(3, 2.0)
        println(x.head / 2 == y.head / 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want conversion to floating point types, then why are you creating lists that have floating point numbers? If you don't want that, just don't stick any floating point numbers in or convert those floating point numbers to non-floating-point numbers.

Comment: Because I want to create such lists, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only two possibilities here: promote to `Double` or widen to `AnyVal`.  In the latter case, division isn't even defined, which is kind of useless.  If you want to demand this behavior, you can explicitly specify the type:

```
val y = List[AnyVal](3,2.0)
y.head match {
  case i: Int => println("Whew, it is still an int!")  // This is printed
  case _ => println("Bah, it messed up again")
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But for other mixed lists compiler automatically chooses AnyVal, or lowest common hierarchical parent.
(example: val x = List(List(1), Vector(1)) //x: List[Seq[Int]] because List[T] is Seq[T] and Vector[T] is Seq[T] for all T)

Behaviour with numeric types seems like exception from rule to me, since Double is not a supertype of Int, because(obviously) Int cannot hold most of valid Double values. _Conversion_, instead, in some cases like this can lead to data loss and i'm surprised that compiler don't even give a warning.

Comment: @SargeBorsch - Given that Java promotes ints to doubles, and given that Scala has borrowed the same policy (presumably to aid adoption and obey the principle of least surprise for Java-users), it makes sense that you ask "hey, can I promote to double?" before asking "hey, can I widen to AnyVal".  Otherwise you end up with weird surprises when you would have anticipated promotion (e.g. `math.max(3,2.0)` and `List(3,2.0).max`).

Comment: May be. It's sad, though. I chose Scala primarily because it's different from Java, to be able to write programs for Android without using Java with its design failures. Seems like it's the only 99% compatible working alternative at the moment.

Comment: @SargeBorsch - It would be nice to have an option to turn it off.  For 90% of uses, though, I'll take the convenience of not needing to throw an extra `.0` or `d` on there where "obviously" supposed to be a double over the occasional possibility for of a type error.  No point being _gratuitously_ different from Java; the policy is not without reason.  (Anyway, I'd turn off `+`-means-string-concat _way_ before I'd turn off `3+3.0`-means-promote-to-double.)

Comment: Type-checking error at compile time is better than runtime error or even wrong result, isn't it?

Comment: @SargeBorsch - If you're likely to make a mistake, yes.  If it's extra work without appreciable benefit, no.  That's why it'd be useful to be able to turn off promotion to double--safety in cases where you anticipate you might make a mistake.  (If you often make this kind of mistake, you could turn it on everywhere.)

Answer (score 2):

`List`s are homogeneously typed.  When you put items of different types into a `List`, the compiler has to figure out what type to give to the whole list.  When you put a Double and an Int into a `List`, Scala decides that the type of the `List` should be `List[Double]` since that is something that both item can be converted to.  See in the REPL:

```
scala> val y = List(3, 2.0)
y: List[Double] = List(3.0, 2.0)
```

The fix is to manually convert your list to be a `List[Int]`:

```
scala> val y = List(3, 2.0).map(_.toInt)
y: List[Int] = List(3, 2)
```

That way, your test comes out `true`:

```
scala> println(x.head / 2 == y.head / 2)
true
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the general problem, that List must have been created heterogenous (for example, List[AnyVal]). I have been always scared by languages that implicitly did type conversions that can lead to data loss. (Int to Long is OK, but Int to Float/Double?)
And my example then shouldn't even compile, and this is good. (Unless we want polymorphic numeric tower, but this is another big topic)

Comment: To be fair, your question is kind of vague about what the "general problem" is.  I read it as "I don't understand why this is happening".  But what you really meant to ask is "Why have the designers of Scala chosen to do it this way?"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want conversion to floating point types, then why are you creating lists that have floating point numbers? If you don't want that, just don't stick any floating point numbers in or convert those floating point numbers to non-floating-point numbers.

Comment: while a very good question, this isn't an answer to the actual question

Comment: ... meanwhile, the question changed. So I think this *was* an answer to the _original_ question. Added it as a comment now though.